# Domain Frame-Forwarding breaks viewport meta settings

Tags: frame, viewport, meta, forwarding

don't know if this is an inappropriate question, it would be great if someone could clear this up for me.

I have one free domain included in my current Internet Contract. Since my Provider does not offer free webspace, i got it somewhere else.

I set the Domain to be a Frame-Redirection to the Webspace, so that I can use the nice and short Url, but so far... this breaks the viewport.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Now I wonder if this is just how it works - or a matter of settings?

Thanks